# Scroll screenshot with footer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Scroll screenshot cannot make if have footer with position absolute.

```
<ScrollView>
...content
</ScrollView>
<View style={position:'absolute', bottom:0}>
Footer
</View>
```

What i should do? without footer scroll screenshot working

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the position of the footer at the bottom so that it won't scroll when you scroll the content.    `position: 'fixed'`

Comment: Footer not scrolling, its works as need, but i cant make screenshot all screen because its nit scrolling down with footer